# How do I implement a find-or-create pattern in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore api has me a little mixed up in trying to have a repeatable pattern for find-or-create style functions.  I'd like the canonical version to look like this:

```
// returns a promise resolving to a DocumentSnapshot (I think??)
function findOrCreateMyObject(myObject) {
    return findMyObject(myObject.identifier).then(documentSnapshot => {
        return (documentSnapshot)? documentSnapshot : createMyObject(myObject);
    });
};
```

I'm not sure if DocumentSnapshot is the appropriate return from this, but I figure the caller may want to inspect *or update* the result, like this:

```
return findOrCreateMyObject({ identifier:'foo' }).then(documentSnapshot => {
    console.log(documentSnapshot.data.someProperty);
    return documentSnapshot.ref.update({ someProperty:'bar' });
});
```

Assuming I am right about that (please tell me if not), it means that both the find and create functions must return a DocumentSnapshot.  This is easy enough for the find...

```
function findMyObject(identifier) {
    let query = db.collection('my-object-collection').where('identifier','=='identifier);
    return query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        return (querySnapshot.docs.length)? querySnapshot.docs[0] : null;
    });
}
```

...but rather awkward for the create, and the the gist of my problem.  I'd want to write create like this....

```
function createMyObject(myObject) {
    // get db from admin
    let collectionRef = db.collection('my-object-collection');
    return db.collection('my-object-collection').doc().set(myObject);
}
```

But I cannot because [DocumentReference `set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) resolves to a "non-null promise containing void".  Void?  I must read back the object I just wrote in order to get a reference to it?  In other words, my idealized create needs to be rewritten to be slower and clunkier...

```
function createMyObject(myObject) {
    // get db from admin
    let collectionRef = db.collection('my-object-collection');
    return db.collection('my-object-collection').doc().set(myObject).then(() => {
        // must we query the thing just written?
        return findMyObject(myObject.identifier);  // frowny face
    });
}
```

This makes my generic create longer (and unnecessarily so when doing *just* a create).  Please tell me:

1. is DocumentSnapshot the right "currency" for these functions to traffic in?
2. Am I stuck with a set() and then *another* query when creating the new object?

Thanks!

**EDIT** As an example of where I would apply this, say I have customers, uniquely identified by email, and they have a status: 'gold', 'silver' or 'bronze'.  My CRM system decides that someone identifying himself as doug@stevenson.com deserves 'silver' status.  We don't know at this point wither Mr. Stevenson is a current customer, so we do a find-or-create...

```
findOrCreateCustomer({ email:'doug@stevenson.com' }).then(customer => {
    customer.update({ status:'silver' });
});
```

I wouldn't just create, because the customer might exist.  I wouldn't just update, because the customer might not exist, or might not meet some other criterion for the update.

Comment: Can you show an example of this pattern elsewhere?  In my experience, creation functions typically don't also fetch, because you already have the data in hand (you just put it in there!).

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, but unless I'm misunderstanding the api (which I might be) firebase puts me in an awkward position:  I have the data I just wrote, yes, but the very next thing I want to do (maybe) is update.  If I am to depend only on what I just wrote, how would I implement the second block of code in my question?  `{ some local model object }` doesn't implement update()

Comment: @DougStevenson your point and my response makes me think maybe my local model should always extend one of the firebase model-ish classes, but if that's right, which one?  DocumentReference?  I don't understand how I would do that either.

Comment: I don't understand the use case of updating a document immediately after creating it.  Wouldn't you just want to just create once with all the necessary data?  This pattern doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DougStevenson - thanks for your patience.  Maybe its not as common of a pattern as I supposed, but it pops up for me when I'm maintaining unique objects (relative to some property or criterion).  Edited to add an example.

Comment: It seems like you want both convenience *and* performance, and these are conflicting with each other.  I have no advice other than to choose one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying.  At present, the api offers me neither.  I think I could have both if `set()` resolved to the document reference of the object just set.

Comment: Or you could just set the entire contents of the document and not do an immediate update.  You already know all the data that should be in the document when you create it.